Cannot read properties of null (reading '__hooks')
In order to use reveal.js in Deno Fresh, I use this code on island:
import { useEffect } from "https://esm.sh/v128/preact@10.19.6/hooks/src/index.js";
import Reveal from '../reveal/js/index.js';

export default function Island() {
  useEffect(()=> {
      setDeck(new Reveal());
      deck.initialize();
  }) 
  return <>Text</>
}

I think this is the correct way to use the hook, but I get this error:
An error occurred during route handling or page rendering. 

  3 |
  4 | export default function Island() {
> 5 |   useEffect(()=> {
    |   ^
  6 |     newFunction();
  7 |
  8 |     function newFunction() {

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '__hooks')
    at s (https://esm.sh/stable/preact@10.19.6/denonext/hooks/src.js:2:1339)
    at G (https://esm.sh/stable/preact@10.19.6/denonext/hooks/src.js:2:2385)
    at Object.Island (file:///D:/Programming/Test/fresh-project/islands/Island.jsx:5:3)
    at m (https://esm.sh/v135/preact-render-to-string@6.3.1/X-ZS8q/denonext/preact-render-to-string.mjs:2:3237)       
    at m (https://esm.sh/v135/preact-render-to-string@6.3.1/X-ZS8q/denonext/preact-render-to-string.mjs:2:2543)       
    at m (https://esm.sh/v135/preact-render-to-string@6.3.1/X-ZS8q/denonext/preact-render-to-string.mjs:2:3802)       
    at m (https://esm.sh/v135/preact-render-to-string@6.3.1/X-ZS8q/denonext/preact-render-to-string.mjs:2:3802)       
    at m (https://esm.sh/v135/preact-render-to-string@6.3.1/X-ZS8q/denonext/preact-render-to-string.mjs:2:3802)       
    at m (https://esm.sh/v135/preact-render-to-string@6.3.1/X-ZS8q/denonext/preact-render-to-string.mjs:2:3802)       
    at m (https://esm.sh/v135/preact-render-to-string@6.3.1/X-ZS8q/denonext/preact-render-to-string.mjs:2:3802)       

What happens?

Yeah I used that path because of this issue: LSP only suggests the src path for all hooks, even when preact has been declared in the import map · Issue #24476 · denoland/deno

You're mixing built, production code and source code (/hooks/src/...), which you cannot do.
Use the built hooks output: https://esm.sh/v128/preact@10.19.6/hooks
